# Open swf file with Matlab

Tags: flash, matlab

I want to open a swf or a flash file with Matlab.I just want matlab to load and play a flah movie. Is that possible? What functions can I use for that.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Somebody made a demo see [Playing with ShockWave Flash movies](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8909-playing-with-shockwave-flash-movies)